# I am trying to generate content from multiple html files on one webpage using a jinja template

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

---

```
index.html
...
...
    <!-- ######################     Main Navigation   ########################## -->
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        {% for href, caption in [('#home','Home'),('#aboutme','About Me'), 
        ('#resume','Portfolio'),('#contact','Contact')] %}
            {% if href == '#home' %}
                <li><a class = "active" href="{{ href }}">{{ caption }}</a></li>
            {% else %}
                <li><a href="{{ href }}">{{ caption }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

    <div class="content">
      {% for item in ['home','aboutme','resume','contact'] %}
      <section id="{{ item }}">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</section>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>

  </body>
  </html>

---------------------
home.html


{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class ="home">
    <h1>My Home page header</h1>
    <p>test text here</p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

As you can see in the pages source code everything is working except between the two section tags. That is where my content from the other file (home.html) should be outputting.[source code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyY35.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're rendering `index.html` you need to change your template like this :

```
index.html
...
...
    <!-- ######################     Main Navigation   ########################## -->
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        {% for href, caption in [('#home','Home'),('#aboutme','About Me'), 
        ('#resume','Portfolio'),('#contact','Contact')] %}
            {% if href == '#home' %}
                <li><a class = "active" href="{{ href }}">{{ caption }}</a></li>
            {% else %}
                <li><a href="{{ href }}">{{ caption }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

    <div class="content">
      {% for item in ['home','aboutme','resume','contact'] %}
      <section id="{{ item }}">{% include 'home.html' %}</section>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>

  </body>
  </html>

---------------------
home.html

<div class ="home">
    <h1>My Home page header</h1>
    <p>test text here</p>
</div>
```

`{% include 'home.html' %}` will put `home.html` content where you use it. You can use it when you want to include another template's content.

`{% extends "index.html" %}` means you're adding more content to the base file which is `index.html` here. You should use it when you're rendering `home.html`. Jinja will not read all the template files before rendering a page to find the blocks and extend tags to include them in your page. that's why your code doesn't work.

Comment: This worked perfectly for putting the home.html content there. Now to iterate through my other 4 pages of content, how can I alter the file within the include statement? So it would cycle through the for loop of items and include each(home,aboutme,resume,contact) each in their own section tag.

Comment: If there's only four sections there then maybe you can remove the for loop and write the tags yourself. if you really want to use the for loop then use jinja `{% if %}...{% elseif %}...{% endif %}` tags inside the loop and check `item` value to include the template for that section. i can update the code if you want.